# What code changes should i make before deploying React and Node website

Tags: reactjs, node.js, deployment

I want to deploy my local project, but dont know what changes should be made in addition to changing the URL.
(maybe some session or cors settings (some new security warnings appeared)).

server:

```
const express = require("express");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const passport = require("passport");
const session = require("express-session");
const passportSteam = require("passport-steam");
const SteamStrategy = passportSteam.Strategy;
const cors = require("cors");
const Review = require("./models/review");

const app = express();
const port = 3001;

app.use(
  cors({
    credentials: true,
    origin: "http://localhost:3000",
  })
); // Adjust 'clientURL' to your actual client URL

// MongoDB connection string
const URLMongoDB =
  "privateInfo";

mongoose
  .connect(URLMongoDB, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true })
  .then(() => console.log("Connected to MongoDB"))
  .catch((err) => console.log(`DB connection error: ${err}`));

passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
  done(null, user);
});

passport.deserializeUser((user, done) => {
  done(null, user);
});

passport.use(
  new SteamStrategy(
    {
      returnURL: "http://localhost:" + port + "/api/auth/steam/return",
      realm: "http://localhost:" + port + "/",
      apiKey: "privateInfo",
    },
    function (identifier, profile, done) {
      process.nextTick(function () {
        profile.identifier = identifier;
        return done(null, profile);
      });
    }
  )
);

app.use(
  session({
    secret: "privateInfo",
    saveUninitialized: true,
    resave: false,
    cookie: {
      maxAge: 3600000,
    },
  })
);
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log("Listening, port " + port);
});

app.use(express.json());
// Routes

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  if (req.user) {
    res.send(req.user);
  } else {
    res.send("No user authenticated");
  }
});

app.get(
  "/api/auth/steam",
  passport.authenticate("steam", { failureRedirect: "/" }),
  function (req, res) {
    res.redirect("http://localhost:3000");
  }
);

app.get(
  "/api/auth/steam/return",
  passport.authenticate("steam", { failureRedirect: "/" }),
  function (req, res) {
    res.redirect("http://localhost:3000");
  }
);

app.post("/api/save-input-review", (req, res) => {
  const review = new Review(req.body);

  review
    .save()
    .then(() => {
      res.sendStatus(200);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error("Error saving review:", error);
      res.sendStatus(500);
    });
});

app.put("/reviews/:id/report", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const reviewId = req.params.id;
    const { inputValueReport } = req.body;

    const updatedReview = await Review.findByIdAndUpdate(
      reviewId,
      { inputValueReport: inputValueReport },
      { new: true }
    );

    res.json(updatedReview);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    res.status(500).json({ error: "Server error" });
  }
});

app.put("/reviews/:id/like", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const reviewId = req.params.id;
    const { liked } = req.body;
    const incrementValue = liked ? 1 : -1;

    const updatedReview = await Review.findByIdAndUpdate(
      reviewId,
      { $inc: { like: incrementValue } },
      { new: true }
    );

    res.json(updatedReview);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    res.status(500).json({ error: "Server error" });
  }
});

app.get("/api/get-all-reviews", (req, res) => {
  Review.find()
    .then((reviews) => {
      res.json(reviews);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error("Error getting reviews:", error);
      res.sendStatus(500);
    });
});
```

client piece of code:

```
useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get("http://localhost:3001/", { withCredentials: true })
      .then((response) => {
        const loggedInValue = response.data.photos[2].value ? true : false;
        setLoggedIn(loggedInValue);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
      });
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get("/api/get-all-reviews")
      .then((response) => {
        setReviews(response.data);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error("Error getting reviews:", error);
      });
  }, []);
```

I've already tried deploying by just changing the urls, but some features aren't working properly